# PHP function executes on same data fine on browser, but receives '502 Gateway error' on iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have an issue where my PHP function runs fine on browser, no error, everything is good. The function is big so I can't really include here. But when iOS runs this function using NSURLConnection POST request, iOS would receive 502 Bad Gateway error nginx. The runtime isn't slow, so it did not timeout.

The fact that on the browser the function executes on the exact same data successfully didn't suggest to me there is any programming error. And if I reduce the size of the data to process, then it would actually run through fine on iOS.

So this seems like it has something to do with iOS' HTTP request somehow has some sort of data size limit that was exceeded resulting in 502 Bad Gateway error. Or there is some header missing that would increase the resource required?

This is my URL request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]  init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue: postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: postData];
```

Comment: Code might be helpful here.

Comment: Open error logs on server and read'em.

Comment: The error log says:

    2016/03/01 13:18:20 [error] 13223#0: *4787043 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 24.114.65.225, server: , request: "POST /debug.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:",

I have already tried increasing the setting fastcgi_buffers 8 4k to 16k:

    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

I should try to increase this further to see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After changing some settings to the following, it still would fail

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Then I found the one setting that worked is:

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128K; (changed from 32K)
```

This setting seems to be directly related to the upstream response buffering.